# Transpose non-word function arguments?

Tags: emacs

When writing Haskell code in Emacs, I often end up in situations where I'd like to change:

```
(foo, [])
```

into

```
([], foo)
```

If Emacs recognized `[]` as a word, then I could just use `M-t` to `transpose-words` and switch them. Is it possible to do this in a way that doesn't break other functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `C-M-t`, which runs the command `transpose-sexps`.

There are quite a few commands starting with `C-M-` that run s-exp commands instead of similar word based commands , such as `C-M-f`/`C-M-b`, forward/backward by s-exp.

Also, there's an Emacs Stack Exchange over at [emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: *This is the best possible answer*, IMO, though it does not answer the question as posed. OP: If you agree, please consider editing your question so that it asks *how to transpose two sexps* (or `[]` and `foo` or whatever). On the other hand, maybe you *really do* want to know how to make `[]` have word syntax...

Comment: @Drew Edited. And thanks, I didn't realize that a bare word was an sexp.

Comment: Thanks. See the Emacs manual, node [Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html), the Elisp manual, node [Intro Eval](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-Eval.html), and [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sexp) for definitions of **sexp**.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun my-transpose-function-args ()
  "Assumes to be called between arguments. "
  (interactive "*")
  (let* ((orig (point))
     (end1 (progn (skip-chars-backward " \t\r\n\f,")
              (point)))
     (beg1
      (progn 
      (skip-chars-backward "^ \t\r\n\f,(")
      (point)))
     (string1 (buffer-substring beg1 end1))
     (beg2 (copy-marker
        (progn (goto-char orig)
               (skip-chars-forward " \t\r\n\f")
               (point))))
     (end2 (copy-marker
        (progn (skip-chars-forward "^ \t\r\n\f,)")
               (point))))
     (string2 (buffer-substring beg2 end2)))
    (goto-char beg1)
    (delete-region beg1 end1)
    (insert string2)
    (goto-char beg2)
    (delete-region beg2 end2)
    (insert string1)))
```